# How to Create Internet explorer Add On that add header to the requests made to a specific host?

Tags: internet-explorer, ieaddon

I want to create an internet explorer extension or add-on that will add header to requests made to a specific host e.g. X-ClientApp-Installed: true.

Comment: any help for this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ (MFC) app with CWebBrowser2 -> ChromeFrame -> HTML5 app, how to get click events from the HTML5 to the C++ app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12800822/c-mfc-app-with-cwebbrowser2-chromeframe-html5-app-how-to-get-click-ev)